# In memory Cockpits in SpagoBI 5 for different users

Tags: spagobi

We met a problem when we build an in-memory cockpits document for different users. 
The problem is, user 'A' built a cockpit, and user 'B' (end-user) wanted to edit it as a template in his personal folder, but he doesn't allowed to do it. Some of the buttons like "add widgets" were missing.

We found that the authorship of this document still was user A, after it had been copied in user B's personal folder. 
Is there any way we could edit the other user's in-memory cockpits as a template, like Qbe?

Thanks!